# RemoveAt(x); Does it dispose the element x?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, list

I have a Cache to store the most two recent images every time the user clicks the next image, Does the "RemoveAt(x)" dispose the x image, or what I want is for the removed image not to be in memory. to be totally removed.

```
 List<Image> BackimageList = new List<Image>();

 private void BackimageListCache(Image img)
{
  BackimageList.Add(img);
  if (BackimageList.Count > 2) 
   {
    BackimageList.RemoveAt(0); //oldest image has index 0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Collections in .NET do not "own" an object.  So they cannot assume that the object isn't used anywhere else, they can thus not dispose the object.  Ownership rules are entirely your own to implement.  Which does imply that you also have to be sure the the image isn't, say, displayed in a PictureBox.

Ensuring the image doesn't occupy *any* memory anymore is iffy as well.  You cannot manage memory yourself, it is the job of the garbage collector.  However, Image uses a rather substantial amount of unmanaged memory to store the pixel data, that memory does get released when you call Dispose().  The managed part of Image stays in memory until the GC gets to it.  It is small.

Comment: You are right, resource was being used else where but I decided to set it now to null and hope for the better. I am a beginner, I think I am still a long way from understanding GC and Dispose.

Comment: The unmanaged part will probably also be cleaned up when the GC gets to it; I'm sure Image has a properly written finalizer.  Of course, [per Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx), "A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run." It's clearly preferable that the Image be disposed immediately after it is no longer needed, rather than when/if the GC gets to it.

Answer (score 15):

The `RemoveAt` method does not call `Dispose` on the image. You will have to dispose it yourself before you call `RemoveAt`.

### Edit

If the type implements `IDisposable`, then to dispose it you write

```
BackImageList[0].Dispose();
BackImageList.RemoveAt(0);
```

`RemoveAt(0)` does, essentially:

```
for (int i = 1; i < BackImageList.Count; ++i)
{
    BackImageList[i-1] = BackImageList[i];
}
BackImageList.Count--;
```

That's all done internally, of course. You can't set the `Count` property. It's done by the `RemoveAt` method.

There is no need to set the value to `null` before calling `RemoveAt`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion By calling Dispose(0) I found out that the resource is being used elsewhere because I got an exception. So I decided to set it to null before removing.    BackimageList[0]=null;
BackimageList.RemoveAt(0);
I hope that will work to save memory in case a user decides to browse 1000 images

Comment: Isn't `[0] == null` and `RemoveAt(0)` the same thing?

Comment: @JimMischel: I don't have the reference source in front of me, but I wouldn't expect `RemoveAt` to include `BackImageList[0] = null;`.  Overwriting `BackImageList[0]` with `BackImageList[1]` during the first iteration of the loop is sufficient to accomplish this task.

Comment: @JimMischel: Thanks for your response. I need to to make sure that BackImageList.Count doesnt exceed 2, I used that conditions some where in my program. If I dont use RemoveAt, the List will continue to grow even though some of the elements will be null.

Comment: @Brian: You're right: it doesn't do `BackImageList[0] = null;`. I was trying to say that it removed the reference, which is why I said "essentially." I suppose my saying that is rather confusing. Thanks for the correction.