# Does Remove method of List dispose object element?

Tags: c#

I want to know if Remove() method of List dispose(destruct) element?

In my code, I have a List type of Timer

```
List<Timer> timerlist;


Timer t = new Timer();
t.Tag = ApptNo.ToString();
t.Interval = ApptInterval * 1000;
t.Tick += tm_Tick;
timerlist.Add(t);
t.Enabled = true;
t.Start();


foreach (Timer t in timerlist)
{
    if (string.Equals(t.Tag, ApptNo.ToString()))
    {
        t.Stop();
        timerlist.Remove(t);
        break;
    }
}
```

My point of question is whether I should dispose timer object t manually or automatically disposed from timerlist.Remove(t).
If t.Dispose() should be called, where should I call it?

Comment: no, it doesn't dispose - you have to do that yourself, presumably right before the `break`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RemoveAt(x); Does it dispose the element x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16181693/removeatx-does-it-dispose-the-element-x) or [Does calling Clear disposes the items also?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49428888/150605)

Answer (score 2):

No, removing from a list doesn't dispose anything - because in the general case, simply being in a list doesn't mean *lifetime ownership*; an object could be in *multiple* lists (or none), and as fields on multiple objects (or none), and in multiple local variables (or none) - so a list cannot assume that removal means the object is doomed.

So: do that yourself when you're sure the object's lifetime is over. In this case, presumably right before you `break`.

Note that it will still be *garbage collected* at some time after the point that is not reachable from anywhere, but usually you should ensure you do your own disposal of `IDisposable` types, *especially* for timers (since timers are essentially "roots").

Comment: Thanks for kind and detailed answer. I could figure it out by your answer